# How can I do to make AutoLayout fit all the size screen of iPhones

Tags: ios, autolayout

actually I'm trying to fit my app for all the size of screen phones, I have a view (the blue square) which contains 2 rectangles at top and bot and 4 squares in the 4 angles of the view and I'm struggling how to make my view (and the contains) have a dynamic resizing on different phone as you can see for the iPhone 4 it takes all the screen... Thanks for the help.
[my AutoLayout image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNBl8.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you set a fixed width constraint (with a constant of `334`) to your blue square view. The smaller iPhones (4s and SE) have a screen width of 320pt, so your blue square view is too wide for them.

You have to make the blue square view's width dynamic (depending on the available screen width)

To achieve that you can set the blue square view's width constraint the be the **same as its superview** (the light blue view) and then define a **multiplier**. For example to define the blue square view's width to be 80% of the available width, you set the multiplier to `0.8`

Here are the steps to set the dynamic width:

1. Delete the fixed width constraint
2. Select the blue square view **and** the light blue view
3. Add a new `Equal Widths`constraint
4. Select the constraint
5. In the **Attributes Inspector** define the `Multiplier`